# How do i go about inserting primary key value into another table primary key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

i have sproc that will perform insert into 2 tables and first table primary key will be inserted into address table (which will be shared with other 5 tables) as address id that i will refer to when i try to pull contact info for particular driver, student ..etc.
as people may say Scope_Identity, which is fine if i have only 2 tables but when i try to insert address scope_ Scope_Identity of table student or driver i might get duplicate or primary key violation.
any idea how to go about doing that to be able to insert driver, students ..etc primary key into address table BE ADVISED that key will be inserted from a text box in a window form OR could any one advise on how to go about doing this operation and how can i improve the sproc

bellow is my sproc which will fail because no identity column is not set

```
USE [GlobalReachCare]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[main_Escort_Insert]    Script Date: 19/04/2014 09:07:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[main_Escort_Insert]

-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@EscortID int,
@FirstName varchar(50),
@Surname varchar(50),
@CrbCheck bit = 0,
@CrbRef varchar(25) = false,
@ExpiryDate date = null,
@Training bit = false,
@TrainingType bit = false,
--@AddressID int,
@Address1 varchar(20),
@Address2 varchar(20)= null,
@Address3 varchar(20) = null,
@City varchar(16),
@PostCode varchar(16),
@Email varchar(50) = null,
@Telephone nvarchar(20),
@DateOfBirth date= null,
@NationalIN nvarchar(25)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Escort int
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
Insert Into dbo.tb_EscortsDetails( EscortId,FirstName,Surname, [CRB_Check], [CRB_Ref],ExpiryDate, Training, TrainingType)
                   VALUES(@EscortId,@FirstName,@Surname,@CrbCheck,@CrbRef,@ExpiryDate,@Training,@TrainingType)

                   set @Escort = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


                   insert into tb_Addresses(AddressID,Address1,address2,Address3,City,PostCode,Email,Telephone,DateOfBirth
                   ,NationalINO)
                   Values(@Escort,@Address1,@Address2,@Address3,@City,@PostCode,@Email,@Telephone,@DateOfBirth,@NationalIN)
END
```

Comment: Has Primary key been used in tb_Addresses or not ?

Comment: really struggling to understand what you are asking, can you show sample data in tables and expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've given the answer yourself:

```
because no identity column is not set
```

Unfortunately you can't add an identity after you've created the table. Try dropping your table and then recreating them. You can do this as followed

```
DROP TABLE tb_EscortsDetails
GO
CREATE TABLE tb_EscortsDetails (
    EscortID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Surname NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CRB_Check BIT NOT NULL,
    CRB_Ref NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    ExpiryDate DATE NOT NULL,
    Training bit NOT NULL,
    TrainingType bit NOT NULL
)

GO
DROP TABLE tb_Addresses 
GO
CREATE TABLE tb_Addresses (
    AddressID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    EscortID INT NOT NULL,
    Address1 NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    address2 NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Address3 NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    City NVARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    PostCode NVARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    Email NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Telephone NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,
    NationalINO  NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (EscortID) REFERENCES tb_EscortsDetails (EscortId)
)
```

And then you can execute your procedure

```
USE [GlobalReachCare]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[main_Escort_Insert]    Script Date: 19/04/2014 09:07:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[main_Escort_Insert]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    --@EscortID int,
    @FirstName varchar(50),
    @Surname varchar(50),
    @CrbCheck bit = 0,
    @CrbRef varchar(25) = false,
    @ExpiryDate date = null,
    @Training bit = false,
    @TrainingType bit = false,
    --@AddressID int,
    @Address1 varchar(20),
    @Address2 varchar(20)= null,
    @Address3 varchar(20) = null,
    @City varchar(16),
    @PostCode varchar(16),
    @Email varchar(50) = null,
    @Telephone nvarchar(20),
    @DateOfBirth date= null,
    @NationalIN nvarchar(25)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Escort int
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Insert Into dbo.tb_EscortsDetails(FirstName,Surname, [CRB_Check], [CRB_Ref],ExpiryDate, Training, TrainingType)
    VALUES(@FirstName,@Surname,@CrbCheck,@CrbRef,@ExpiryDate,@Training,@TrainingType)

    set @Escort = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    insert into tb_Addresses(EscortID,Address1,address2,Address3,City,PostCode,Email,Telephone,DateOfBirth,NationalINO)
    Values(@EscortID,@Address1,@Address2,@Address3,@City,@PostCode,@Email,@Telephone,@DateOfBirth,@NationalIN)
END
```

Be sure to replace your CREATE TABLE columns with the data types you want to use

Hope this helps!

Comment: Victor, you save me alot of time as i completely forgot about the foreign keys as i only started with T-SQL only recently. this exactly what i want thank you for your effort and time

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark my comment as an answer if you please :)

Comment: Hi Victor as the above will work fine with only escort table but if i have another other 4 tables i'll need to have a foreign key in address table for each of them and I'll end up having empty foreign keys in one row as escort, driver or students will be inserted separately. what i mean escort details will be inserted seprate from students seprate from driver details. what i was thinking is a column that it's value can be inserted from 4 other sproc similar to the above sproc.